# How can I use static variables in express js?

Tags: reactjs, express

```
const React = require('react');

class ProductsToolbar extends React.Component {
  static storagePrefix = 'prefix_';
}
```

throws an error:

```
ERROR in ./app/components/ProductsToolbar.jsx
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/jsx-loader/index.js):
Error: Parse Error: Line 4: Unexpected identifier
    at throwError (/Volumes/Projects/node-express/abc-category/node_modules/esprima-fb/esprima.js:2818:21)
```

But static functions work fine??

webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  context: path.join(__dirname, './'),
  entry: './app/app.jsx',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'jsx-loader',
        include: path.join(__dirname, 'app'),
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`static` keyword should work in your case, I think your error tells you that it does not understand `class` or `static` keyword.

Your `webpack.config.js` is missing babel and es6 classes tramspiler, you probably need to add babel-loader with `@babel/plugin-transform-classes` and `@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties`

And for transpiling `.jsx` it's a good practice to use `babel-loader` with `@babel/preset-react` preset.

Comment: Seems like `jsx-loader` does transpile it but have they forgotten static variables maybe? since functions are fine

Comment: that problem is quite strange, because you static keyword by all means should work without problems, actual problem might be in webpack loaders themselves, suggest adding `babel` just in case these errors come up in the future. There is specific babel transpiler for this `@babel/preset-react`

Comment: I was using `jsx-loader` instead of babel but that seems very old and depcreated, copied from a (strange, old) boilerplate project